# Meaning of の 〜でも

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to translate this sentence but there are some points that I do not understand.

特に｛雪｝と言う最近の小説は、のアメリカでも、チュウテンチツチのテロがあり注目を集めていきましたけれども」

First of all, what's the reason of using America inbetween "の" and "でも"? I believe the reason is to put emphasis but I'm not sure.

Second, what the hell is チュウテンチツチ? I've done hundreds of google search and I still have no clue. Maybe it's a simple mispelling but I don't know. This is a sentence of Kenzaburo Oe by the way.

Thank you :3

Comment: Hi, I have several portions uncomfortable with your transcription. Could you put an image of original printing or some? A wider context would be more appreciated.

Comment: He is talking about a Turkish writer called "Orhan Pamuk" and "Kar (Yuki)" that is his novel. "Kar" is about culture clash between Western and Eastern values. I believe he wants to say Americans love that novel since there has been issues with Muslim Terror in their country.

「パムックはね、おもしろいことに、５年ごとくらいに自分で主題を決めて、確率な新しい小説を書くんです。彼はいま７册くらい小説の基本がありますが、1つ1つが方法が変わっている主題も変わっている。特に｛雪｝と言う最近の小説は、のアメリカでも、チュウテンチツチのテロがあり注目を集めていきましたけれども」

The whole quotation is stated above.

Comment: Sorry, is it audio? Where can I have it? I'm almost sure that what you're asking is wrong hearing of "9.11", among a few more possible errors.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the audio, but I believe these are the subtitles heard and written by a non-native Japanese speaker. You're probably right though, It must be 9/11. Thank you1

Comment: Oh I thought it was an artifact of YouTube's auto caption generation which often outputs such kind of half-bad sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nine eleven in Japanese can be pronounced as 9(きゅう) .(てん) 1(いち) 1(いち), so I echo @Bilge that チュウテンチツチ is pretty clearly a mis-transcription of 9.11. No humans would do this, so I'm willing to bet this is machine translation.

のアメリカでも used like this is also grammatically incorrect, and a mis-transcription explains that one well, too.